# BOOL array in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, nsarray

How can I declare an array of BOOL as a property in an Objective-C class? This is not correct:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray<BOOL> *checked;
```

Comment: You can't put primitive (BOOL, int, CGPoint, etc) into a `NSArray`, only objects. A way to do so is to encapulsate them into `NSNumber` or `NSValue` for the most common ones.

Comment: Simply you can intiialize like this -> `type arrayName [ arraySize ];` -> `BOOL arrayName [5];` 

`BOOL arrayName[3] = { YES, NO, YES };`

Comment: this is an old c way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `NSNumber` and init them with: `- (NSNumber *)initWithBool:(BOOL)value;`. So the property should look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray<NSNumber *> *checked;
```

Comment: You should use modern syntax: `@(boolValue)`